# Xmonad configuration file issue

Tags: configuration, xmonad

I am using Xmonad since long time now and it works well, execept  I can not modify the configuration file xmonad.hs because there are some strange errors even with the basic configuration;
my actual file is :

```
import XMonad
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig
    {borderWidth =1
    , terminal = "urxvt"
    , normalBorderColor = "#cccccc"
    , focusedBorderColor = "#cd8b00" }
```

when I check the file I get this:

```
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__hsunix_wifexited'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_wexitstatus':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x10): multiple definition of `__hsunix_wexitstatus'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x10): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_wifsignaled':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `__hsunix_wifsignaled'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x20): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_wtermsig':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x40): multiple definition of `__hsunix_wtermsig'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-    2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x40): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In     function `__hsunix_wifstopped':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `__hsunix_wifstopped'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-  2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x50): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_wstopsig':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x60): multiple definition of `__hsunix_wstopsig'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x60): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_SIGWINCH':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x70): multiple definition of `__hsunix_SIGWINCH'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x70): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_push_module':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x80): multiple definition of `__hsunix_push_module'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-   2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x80): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_long_path_size':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x90): multiple definition of `__hsunix_long_path_size'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x90): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_unsetenv':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0xa0): multiple definition of `__hsunix_unsetenv'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-    2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0xa0): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hscore_setrlimit':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0xb0): multiple definition of `__hscore_setrlimit'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-  2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0xb0): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In   function `__hscore_getrlimit':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0xc0): multiple definition of `__hscore_getrlimit'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-  2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0xc0): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In   function `__hscore_mkstemp':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0xd0): multiple definition of `__hscore_mkstemp'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-  2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0xd0): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In   function `__hsunix_unlockpt':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0xe0): multiple definition of `__hsunix_unlockpt'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-  2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0xe0): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In function `__hsunix_grantpt':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0xf0): multiple definition of `__hsunix_grantpt'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-  2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0xf0): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In  function `__hsunix_ptsname':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x100): multiple definition of `__hsunix_ptsname'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-    2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x100): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In   function `__hsunix_mknod':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x180): multiple definition of `__hsunix_mknod'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-    2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x110): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(HsUnix.o): In     function `__hsunix_lstat':
HsUnix.c:(.text+0x1c0): multiple definition of `__hsunix_lstat'
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/unix-2.3.2.0/libHSunix-2.3.2.0.a(HsUnix.o):HsUnix.c:(.text+0x150): first defined here
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/base-4.1.0.0/libHSbase-4.1.0.0.a(PrelIOUtils.o): In function   `__hscore_d_name':
PrelIOUtils.c:(.text+0x1c0): multiple definition of `__hscore_d_name'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-  2.4.0.0.a(dirUtils.o):dirUtils.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/local/lib/ghc-6.10.3/base-4.1.0.0/libHSbase-4.1.0.0.a(PrelIOUtils.o): In function `__hscore_free_dirent':
PrelIOUtils.c:(.text+0x580): multiple definition of `__hscore_free_dirent'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-  2.4.0.0.a(dirUtils.o):dirUtils.c:(.text+0x10): first defined here
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function   `slqz_info':
(.text+0x227f): undefined reference to `fcntl_read'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function `slqz_info':
(.text+0x22ab): undefined reference to `fcntl_read'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function     `skA0_info':
(.text+0x2358): undefined reference to `fcntl_write'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function         `skAq_info':
(.text+0x240f): undefined reference to `fcntl_write'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function     `slwb_info':
(.text+0x2703): undefined reference to `fcntl_read'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function     `slwb_info':
(.text+0x272f): undefined reference to `fcntl_read'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function     `slzG_info':
(.text+0x29a3): undefined reference to `fcntl_lock'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function     `slCa_info':
(.text+0x2b73): undefined reference to `fcntl_lock'
/home/giuseppe/.cabal/lib/unix-2.4.0.0/ghc-6.10.3/libHSunix-2.4.0.0.a(IO.o): In function     `slFq_info':
(.text+0x2dff): undefined reference to `fcntl_lock'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please check the file for errors.
```

can somebody help me? I would like configure xmonad to use xmobar, but If not even the simplest configuration works, iI do not know how to do it, I know that xmonad is using the last working configuration, maybe I can find it and modify, I do not know I am confused, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 versions of "unix" haskell library: system one and for your local user giuseppe. You can try hiding the last one just for recompiling the xmonad config, unhide it later.

```
ghc-pkg hide --user unix-2.4.0.0
```